# Do While loop does not stop after meeting the condition

Tags: fortran, do-while

I have written the following code for the bisection method in Fortran, but it does not stop after meeting conditions that I have defined in the Do While loop. Any explanations would be appreciated.

```
! Bi-section method
program bi_section 
implicit none

!Variables
real :: a, b, p  
real :: fa, fb, fp, fc

! Interval
a = 2.0
b = 3.0

! Value of fa & fb
fa = a*a*a-13
fb = b*b*b-13

    do while (abs(fb-fa) > 0.00001)
    p = (a+b)/2
    fp = p*p*p-13
        if (fp*fa > 0) then
            a = p
        else
            b = p      
        end if
    print*, p
    enddo
end program bi_section
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Why do you believe the condition was met? Please read [ask] and show us the output of your program, it is good to print the values of `fa` and `fb` to see what the condition does.

Comment: Since neither `fa` nor `fb` is updated inside the loop it's unreasonable to expect `abs(fb-fa)` to change.

Answer (score 2):

To find a possible bug, a good approach is to print the values of relevant variables  (e.g. `a`, `b`, `fa`, and `fb`) and check whether things are going as expected. For example,

```
do while (abs(fb-fa) > 0.00001)
    p = (a+b)/2
    fp = p*p*p-13
    if (fp*fa > 0) then
        a = p
    else
        b = p      
    end if
    !-- print*, p
    print*, p, a, b, fa, fb    !<--- print more variables for check
enddo
```

the above print statement gives

```
   2.50000000       2.00000000       2.50000000      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.25000000       2.25000000       2.50000000      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.37500000       2.25000000       2.37500000      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.31250000       2.31250000       2.37500000      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.34375000       2.34375000       2.37500000      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35937500       2.34375000       2.35937500      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35156250       2.34375000       2.35156250      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.34765625       2.34765625       2.35156250      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.34960938       2.34960938       2.35156250      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35058594       2.35058594       2.35156250      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35107422       2.35107422       2.35156250      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35131836       2.35131836       2.35156250      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35144043       2.35131836       2.35144043      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35137939       2.35131836       2.35137939      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35134888       2.35131836       2.35134888      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35133362       2.35133362       2.35134888      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35134125       2.35133362       2.35134125      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35133743       2.35133362       2.35133743      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35133553       2.35133362       2.35133553      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35133457       2.35133457       2.35133553      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   2.35133505       2.35133457       2.35133505      -5.00000000       14.0000000
   ...
```

So, although `p` is approaching the correct solution (cubic root of 13 = 2.3513346...), neither `fa` nor `fb` does not change and the "condition" (`abs(fb-fa) <= 0.00001`) is never met (as suggested by @HighPerformanceMark in the comment). To avoid this, we need to update `fa` and `fb`, for example,

```
do while (abs(fb-fa) > 0.00001)
    p = (a+b)/2
    fp = p*p*p-13
    if (fp*fa > 0) then
        a = p
        fa = fp  !<---
    else
        b = p
        fb = fp  !<---
    end if
    print*, p, a, b, fa, fb
enddo
```

which gives

```
   2.50000000       2.00000000       2.50000000      -5.00000000       2.62500000
   2.25000000       2.25000000       2.50000000      -1.60937500       2.62500000
   2.37500000       2.25000000       2.37500000      -1.60937500      0.396484375
   2.31250000       2.31250000       2.37500000     -0.633544922      0.396484375
   2.34375000       2.34375000       2.37500000     -0.125396729      0.396484375
   2.35937500       2.34375000       2.35937500     -0.125396729      0.133815765
   2.35156250       2.34375000       2.35156250     -0.125396729       3.77845764E-03
   2.34765625       2.34765625       2.35156250      -6.09159470E-02   3.77845764E-03
   2.34960938       2.34960938       2.35156250      -2.85959244E-02   3.77845764E-03
   2.35058594       2.35058594       2.35156250      -1.24149323E-02   3.77845764E-03
   2.35107422       2.35107422       2.35156250      -4.32014465E-03   3.77845764E-03
   2.35131836       2.35131836       2.35156250      -2.70843506E-04   3.77845764E-03
   2.35144043       2.35131836       2.35144043      -2.70843506E-04   1.75380707E-03
   2.35137939       2.35131836       2.35137939      -2.70843506E-04   7.41004944E-04
   2.35134888       2.35131836       2.35134888      -2.70843506E-04   2.35557556E-04
   2.35133362       2.35133362       2.35134888      -1.71661377E-05   2.35557556E-04
   2.35134125       2.35133362       2.35134125      -1.71661377E-05   1.08718872E-04
   2.35133743       2.35133362       2.35133743      -1.71661377E-05   4.48226929E-05
   2.35133553       2.35133362       2.35133553      -1.71661377E-05   1.33514404E-05
   2.35133457       2.35133457       2.35133553      -1.90734863E-06   1.33514404E-05
   2.35133505       2.35133457       2.35133505      -1.90734863E-06   6.67572021E-06
```

(By the way, we can write `p*p*p-13` as `p**3 - 13`).

Comment: @Appif Please *do* take the [tour] I linked for you above. Among other useful stuff you will find out how to accept answers. Do also see the other link. It is generally good to try to respond to comments under your question, especially when they ask something. I don't know who and why downvoted your question, but it may be connected with the lack of your responses.